# Terragrunt Best practice: dependencies between modules

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I have a terragrunt project like this

```
├── common_vars.hcl
├── envs
│   ├── dev
│   │   ├── env_vars.hcl
│   │   ├── rds-aurora
│   │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   ├── rds-sg
│   │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   │   └── vpc
│   │       └── terragrunt.hcl
│   └── prod
│       ├── env_vars.hcl
│       ├── rds-sg
│       │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│       └── vpc
│           └── terragrunt.hcl
├── modules
│   ├── aws-data
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   └── outputs.tf
│   ├── rds-aurora
│   │   └── main.tf
│   ├── rds-sg
│   │   └── main.tf
│   └── vpc
│       └── main.tf
└── terragrunt.hcl
```

The *rds-sg* is the security group depends on the vpc.
The *terragrunt.hcl* under dev and prod has the same code like this.

```
terraform {
  source = format("%s/modules//%s", get_parent_terragrunt_dir(), path_relative_to_include())
}

include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

dependencies {
  paths = ["../vpc"] # not dry
}

dependency "vpc" {
  config_path = "../vpc" # not dry
}

inputs = {

   vpc_id = dependency.vpc.outputs.vpc_id # if something changes or we need more inputs

}
```

As described in the comments, some codes are not so DRY. If I want to change something like change to another vpc or add more inputs, then I need to modify this file everywhere.

So I want something in the *main.tf* under modules

```
module "rds-sg" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws//modules/mysql"

  name = "${var.name_prefix}-db-sg"

  description = "Security group for mysql 3306 port open within VPC"


  vpc_id = ""
  # I want something like
  # vpc_id = dependency.vpc.outputs.vpc_id

}
```

Is that possible? or some better practices to solve this problem?
Thanks very much.

Maybe using terraform_remote_state can fix this problem. Any better idea?

This comment may explain this problem better.
https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/759#issuecomment-687610130

Comment: The newly(maybe) added offical documents may be a right answer. 
https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-terragrunt-architecture-dry/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Data sources to read any ID for any resources:
Add this to the module that uses VPC ID.

```json
data "aws_vpc" "this" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = [var.name]
  }
}
...
vpc_id            = data.aws_vpc.this.id
```

This way you are making sure to read from AWS API not from State file, which has on plan validation also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I also tried this way and it seems that to share something like var.name, or when it is needed to create a lot of data-source with different service and alias, the situation becomes very confused. Maybe the common best practice is better.